# Facebook API in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, facebook-graph-api

If anyone has experience with the Facebook API,
What I’m trying to do is have a logged-in FB user, in my FB app, be able to browse photos uploaded by friends [not necessarily with themselves in those photos -- but just to see photos by their friends]. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. It depends on how you want these photos to be displayed. 
I have never connected the facebook API with any Flex app but I have experience with projects that use Iframe to display HTML content in FLex apps. You can find the Iframe project here:
[iframe project](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/). In my opinion you can generate these photos in a php script that uses the 
facebook API and display its result as Iframe in your Flex application.
I've described the way how the IFrame can be used on my blog here:
[Iframe in Flex](http://flex-blogger.com/blog/2010/12/11/flex-and-html-embedded-in-iframe/) . I use this approach very often and I've never had any problem with it.

Comment: You could also use HTTPService to connect to such a php/asp/whatever script. The script would get these photos using the facebook API and return them as XML/JSON. That's a good approach too.